# Count features on geometric network between two points

Tags: arcpy, python, geometric-network

What geoprocessing tool or process will let me count the point features on a geometric network between a specified start and end point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a correctly configured geometric network you can use the [Utility Network analyst toolbar](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geometric-networks/using-the-utility-network-analyst-toolbar-about-th.htm) to create a route between your start and end points. Then use the route in a select by location tool to select the point features. The selection is the count but you could also then filter those points on any criteria you choose.